# C# Console Application connecting to Exchange Online

Tags: c#, exchange-server, office365, exchangewebservices

I have a c# console app written to manipulate a mailbox currently hosted on an Exchange 2010 server. I'm leveraging EWS to connect to the box using AutoDiscover.

In the near future this mailbox will be moving to Exchange Online (as part of a migration to Office365). From what I've been reading, it appears the app will have to be registered in Azure AD. Is this the case, or will AutoDiscover continue to function as is?

Comment: Just as an FYI, I was able to use straight EWS, but had explicitly define the ExchangeService Credentials and Url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AutoDiscover works with Exchange Online. However, if are running your own DNS for the e-mail domain the administrator will have to configure the required DNS record. Exactly which DNS records are required for your domain is displayed in the Office365 portal.

Comment: Thanks! So no need to register in Azure AD?

Comment: @philorube: I don't see why. Outlook has no problems using AutoDiscover with Exchange Online and I don't think that app is registered in Azure AD. To be honest I don't know what you mean by "register in Azure AD". My understanding is that AutoDiscover is a DNS record that helps retrieve an XML file with the necessary information to connect to EWS and this information is available to any application.

Comment: It must be only required if you're using the Outlook Mail REST API. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations